# How to position Firebase Admob on the bottom after keyboard is closed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

I am using firebase_admob package. I use the following code and manage to make the Admob banner show on top of keyboard.

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        myBanner.show(
          anchorOffset: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom, anchorType: AnchorType.bottom)
        );

    return Scaffold(
      //Other codes
        );
    }
```

However, when the keyboard is closed, the banner won't move to bottom. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by using `[admob_flutter]` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) which can simply add the banner as a widget and we can position it anywhere we want.

```
AdmobBanner(
  adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
  adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
)
```

Comment: Anyone tried [admob_flutter] is it safe since it is not official? I haven't inspect the code so I don't know what is happening under the hood.

Comment: This plugin is good but at same time it also has some major bugs. It just crashes the app in a lot of scenarios. PLEASE TELL ANY ALTERNATIVE....

Comment: Should we use firebase_admob and admob_flutter? Or can we just use admob_flutter? and why we should use firebase_admob? I mean in what case?

Comment: firebase_admob is the so called official package. Although admob_flutter is not officially maintained by Google team, we can see from the source code, it is using the official Admob SDK.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [keyobar_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) plugin to change the banner place

```dart
  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
      // Change the your myBanner.show parameters here with setState
      // anchorOffset and anchorType
    },
  );
```

Comment: Thanks but why with MediaQuery, I successfully made the banner move up when keyboard open, but why the banner won't move down when keyboard is closed?